# Symfony 3.3.16 form not rendering as multipart

Tags: php, forms, symfony

My Symfony 3.3.16 app is not rendering the form opening tag in the expected way.

I am using a FormType in order to create the form:

```
class UserTypeIdentify extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
        $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('aFile', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Upload file', 'required' => false))

...
```

In my Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(UserTypeIdentify::class, $user);
....
```

In my template:

```
<?php echo $view['form']->start($form); ?>
```

Outputs this:

```
<form method="post">
```

even though I am using *FileType::class*, it does not render the proper enctype, thus not submitting files .
I've also tried using

```
<?php echo $view['form']->start($form, ['attr' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
```

without any success. Any tips?

Comment: How `$view['form']` is defined? What is in the `$user` variable? Is it a form with `data_class` specified? If yes then does the Entity have `aFile` property defined?

Comment: `$view['form']` is Symfonys form helper, `$form` is populated by $form->createView() in the controller. `$user` is the User entity, `data_class` is pointing to User entity, aFile property is included and also having an `@Assert\File` annotation, type is blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was an open, legacy

```
<form method="post">
```

in my template. Thus Symfony's one was ignored.